# Why cookies is not been deleted and user is still logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I have login function in MVC3.

```
private bool UserControll(string name, string password, string token = null)
{
    User user;
user = userRepos.LogOn(name, password, Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
if (user.IsAuthenticated)
{
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket;
        authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.SessionId, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), false, "");

        string cookieContents = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieContents)
             {
                 Expires = authTicket.Expiration,
                 Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
             };

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

I can not figure out why cookies is not been deleted after 1 minute (just for testing, look at DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)). When I check cookies in FireFox at the start of the session it shows: Expires: 29.08.2011 12:07 (current time + one minutes). After one minutes it shows: Expires: At end of session. Session is not deleted, user is not logged out.

I can not understand why the cookie is not been deleted and user is not logged out.

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned Cookie expiry time. Also you can use `Session.Clear();` to clear all sessions.

Create a logout page in which use `Session.Clear();` function in page On_Load() function. This  results clearing all session created in your page.

Answer (score 1):

After you have reached the expiry date of the cookie, did you make a request to site before checking if the cookie has been removed? Because cookie doesn't get removed until you make a request.